# Electric field of point charge that has circular motion

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

We know that moving charge in constant velocity has deformed equation of electric field.

$$ E = k \frac{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}{\left[1-\frac{v^2 \sin^2\theta}{c^2}\right]^{3/2}}  \frac{q}{R^2}$$

We can derive this equation by put zero vector into acceleration term.
But what if the charge has a circular motion? What will the equation be?

Comment: We have MathJax active on the site which means that you can write mathematics that will be neatly typeset in a LaTeX-math-mode-alike language. I'll do this one for you. You should check, BTW, that I've done it right.

Comment: Do you mean that small charge is moving on a circular orbit much bigger than its size? Then you would get radiation emission. This is a very well-known problem. The relevant search term is 'cyclotron radiation'

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation. The fields can be derived from the Lienard-Wiechert potentials for a charge in *arbitrary* motion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liénard–Wiechert_potential

Comment: Everybody thanks a lot! I appreciate it!

Comment: Are you the inertial or accelerated observer?

Comment: The inertial observer, I guess.

Comment: @Cyro: it's not clear if the cyclotron is a good example since the electrons are being accelerated by a constant magnetic field.

Comment: @littlegiant: okay - I'll play with it this weekend. I'm more interested in "fictitious" forces in the accelerated frame.